# Python Concatenate Bytes

Tags: python

how concatenate bytes eg. sample code:

```
data_bs = ''
c = b'\x00\x00\xa0\xe1\x00'

for i in list(range(0, len(c), 2)):
    data_bs += c[i+1] + c[i]
```

Error code:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Im want fix byte order.

Comment: You should try using `io.BytesIO` if you want to append into some buffer

Comment: theirs another issue with your code, you recive a `IndexError: index out of range`

Comment: @ClownDown when replaced to b'' : TypeError: can't concat int to bytes

Comment: data_bs is a string, c is bytes, c[i] is a byte, you have the types mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing into bytes directly gives an `int`, so the easiest solution here is to just make `data_bs` into `bytes` and use slices:

```
In [132]: data_bs = b''
     ...: c = b'\x00\x00\xa0\xe1\x00'
     ...:
     ...: for i in list(range(0, len(c), 2)):
     ...:     data_bs += c[i+1:i+2] + c[i:i+1]
     ...:

In [133]: data_bs
Out[133]: b'\x00\x00\xe1\xa0\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're trying to concatenate them into from the question. However, if you want to create a string like `data_bs` implies you can do this:

```
for i in c:
    data_bs += str(i)
print(data_bs)
```

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, preallocate the output array and then copy bytes in the order you require e.g.

```
a = b'\x00\x01\x02\x03'
b = bytearray(len(a))

for cnt in range(0, int(len(a) / 2)):
    b[cnt * 2] = a[cnt * 2 + 1]
    b[cnt * 2 + 1] = a[cnt * 2]

print(a)
print(b)
```

consider what to do if the length is odd e.g.

```
if len(a) % 2 == 1:
    b[len(a) - 1] = a[len(a) - 1]
```